# Using Mac OSX Dictation with Speech API

Tags: macos, speech-recognition, dictation

In OSX Mavericks, speech dictation is now included, and is very useful. I am trying to use the dictation capability to create my own digital life assistant, but I can't find how to use the recognition functionality to get the speech in an application rather than a text box.

I have looked into NSSpeechRecognizer, but that seems to be geared toward programming speakable commands with a pre-defined grammar rather than dictation. It doesn't matter what programming language I use, but Python or Java would be nice...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: any solutions since?

Comment: @NicolasManzini yes see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SFSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190615210258/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech)) (requires [macOS 10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina)+): this is made for speech recognition.

> Perform speech recognition on live or prerecorded audio, receive transcriptions, alternative interpretations, and confidence levels of the results.

Whereas as you have noted in the question [NSSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechrecognizer) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190615210317/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechrecognizer)) indeed provides a “command and control” style of voice recognition system (the command phrases must be defined prior to listening, in contrast to a dictation system where the recognized text is unconstrained).

From https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/256/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190616031354/https://theconversation.com/assets/logo-192x192-0dc138eb03a755cacf6c3df151929282.png)):

[image]

Another way is to directly use Mac Dictation, but as far as I know the only way is to rerdirect audio feeds, which isn't very neat, e.g. see http://www.showcasemarketing.com/ideablog/transcribe-mp3-audio-to-text-mac-os/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190615211244/http://www.showcasemarketing.com/ideablog/transcribe-mp3-audio-to-text-mac-os/)).