# API for Enhanced Dictation on OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been searching for a few days regarding Speech to Text on OS X.
I'm looking to offline convert natural language to text for a personal project. I would like to do this without a third party API, and that's where the trouble seems to lie.

Enhanced dictation in 10.9 and up seems to be the perfect solution for this, because it is offline and converts extremely quickly. 
NSSpeechRecognizer is great for commands you ask for, but isnt fast, and doesnt convert entire phrases.

Another idea I had was programmatically enable dictation on the fly, then pipe audio into it, then pipe the resulting text back into my program.

I can't seem to find any documentation on an API to access the inbuilt Enhanced Dictation.

Any ideas?

Using swift for the first time, but not new to OOP.

Comment: There's a [session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/) at this year WWDC that talks about speech recognition. Don't know if it will be available in OS X Sierra though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956946/using-mac-osx-dictation-with-speech-api